# Drag and drop with protractor not working in different browsers?

Tags: javascript, firefox, jenkins, drag-and-drop, protractor

I have below code which is working fine in local machine, Chrome environment considering drag and drop:

```
browser.actions().dragAndDrop(elem1, elem2).mouseUp().perform();
```

But the same code throwing error in Jenkins environment in Firefox browser:

```
[e2e] [firefox #11-1] [31m    Failed: UnknownError: Cannot release a button when no button is pressed.'UnknownError: Cannot release a button when no button is pressed.' when calling method: [wdIMouse::up]
[e2e] [firefox #11-1]     Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 17:00:58'
[e2e] [firefox #11-1]     System info: host: '6b46e0e227dc', ip: '172.17.0.3', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-327.13.1.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_03-Ubuntu'
[e2e] [firefox #11-1]     Driver info: driver.version: unknown[0m
[e2e] [firefox #11-1]   Stack:
```

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong with syntax:

```
browser.actions().dragAndDrop(elem1, elem2).mouseUp().perform();
```

Should be changed to:

```
browser.actions().dragAndDrop(elem1, elem2).perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

try to do the same without `.mouseUp()`, in case of `.dragAndDrop()` already has it.

[dragAndDrop](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/ab1e647d0fc8fc39e6b00ae94321ab228b6728f2/javascript/webdriver/actionsequence.js#L218-L229) behind the scenes is mouseDown + mouseMove + mouseUp:

```
/**
 * Convenience function for performing a "drag and drop" manuever. The target
 * element may be moved to the location of another element, or by an offset (in
 * pixels).
 * @param {!webdriver.WebElement} element The element to drag.
 * @param {(!webdriver.WebElement|{x: number, y: number})} location The
 *     location to drag to, either as another WebElement or an offset in pixels.
 * @return {!webdriver.ActionSequence} A self reference.
 */
webdriver.ActionSequence.prototype.dragAndDrop = function(element, location) {
  return this.mouseDown(element).mouseMove(location).mouseUp();
};
```

Comment: @Mithun , please mark your or my answer. It will show to another users that this question has answer.